# Sorting sequentially

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Having an unordered array containing two distincts elements :

```
arr = ["portrait", "landscape", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape", "landscape"]
```

Given this example, looking into 'sorting' the array to have one `landscape` every four `portraits`:

```
4 portraits
1 landscape
4 portraits
1 landscape
...
```

If not a one liner, what would be the shortest way to achieve such goal?

Comment: There's one missing "portrait", what's your expected output, what are the scenarios to cover?

Comment: Rather than "sorting" the array, you could gather total counts of landscape and portrait entries and create a new array with elements in the correct positions. This allows you to easily handle the case where there aren't enough "landscape" available and gives you easy control of the output order.

Comment: 'With a fallback'. Okay what's the fallback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if the number of "portraits" doesn't "coincide" with the number of "landscapes" then it'd add the remaining ones in a row:

```
arr = %w[portrait landscape portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait landscape landscape]
landscapes, portraits =  arr.sort.slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.to_a
p portraits.each_slice(4).flat_map.with_index { |e, i| e << landscapes[i] }.compact

# ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you mean by fallback, here is an illustration of how to achieve what you want. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it's simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

arr = (['P'] * 32 + ['L'] * 12).shuffle  # as an example
ps, ls = arr.partition { |element| element == 'P' }
result = []

loop do
    portrait_count = [4, ps.size].min
    portrait_count.times { result << ps.shift }

    landscape_count = [1, ls.size].min
    landscape_count.times { result << ls.shift }

    break if ps.empty? && ls.empty?
end

puts result.each_slice(5) { |slice| p slice }

=begin
Outputs:
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["P", "P", "P", "P", "L"]
["L", "L", "L", "L"]
=end
```

I'm assuming there is more to each object than merely a 'portrait' or 'landscape' switch, and that's why I get the elements out of the array in order.

Comment: Keith, I added your solution to the benchmark. I don't know how I missed it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This method emphasizes computational efficiency. I count the number of "portrait"'s in the array and from that compute the number of groups of four and the numbers of remaining "portrait"'s and "landscape"'s. I then uses those three quantities to constructs the desired array, which does not require any iterative steps.

**Code**

```
def rearrange(arr)
  nbr_portraits = arr.count("portrait")
  nbr_landscapes = arr.size - nbr_portraits
  groups_of_4_portraits = [nbr_portraits/4, nbr_landscapes].min 
  nbr_portraits -= 4 * groups_of_4_portraits
  nbr_landscapes -= groups_of_4_portraits
  [*[*["portrait"]*4, "landscape"]*groups_of_4_portraits,
   *["portrait"] * nbr_portraits, *["landscape"] * nbr_landscapes] 
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = ["portrait", "landscape", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait",
       "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait",
       "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait",
      "landscape", "landscape"]

rearrange arr
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]   

rearrange %w| portrait portrait portrait landscape portrait portrait
              portrait portrait portrait portrait |
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]

rearrange %w| portrait portrait portrait portrait portrait |
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]

rearrange %w| landscape landscape portrait landscape portrait |
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "landscape", "landscape", "landscape"]

rearrange %w| landscape landscape landscape landscape |
  #=> ["landscape", "landscape", "landscape", "landscape"]

rearrange []
  #=> []
```

**Explanation**

For `arr` above the steps are as follows.

```
nbr_portraits = arr.count("portrait")
  #=> 17
nbr_landscapes = arr.size - nbr_portraits
  #=> 3
groups_of_4_portraits = [nbr_portraits/4, nbr_landscapes].min
  #=> 3
nbr_portraits -= 4 * groups_of_4_portraits
  #=> 5
nbr_landscapes -= groups_of_4_portraits
  #=> 0
b = ["portrait"] * 4
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]
c = [*b, "landscape"]
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape"]
d = c * groups_of_4_portraits
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape"]
e = ["portrait"] * nbr_portraits
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]
f = ["landscape"] * nbr_landscapes
  #=> []
[*d, *e, *f]
  #=> ["portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "landscape",
  #    "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait", "portrait"]
```

**Quick Benchmark**

Here I am comparing the above method with Sebastian's and Keith's solutions. The results are not directly comparable because we understood the question differently. Keith and I put any left-over "portrait"'s or "landscape"'s at the end ("portrait"'s first), whereas Sebastian puts only left-over "portrait"'s at the end, discarding any left-over "landscape"'s.

```
require 'fruity'

np = 100
nl = 120

p (arr = [*["portrait"]*np, *["landscape"]*nl].shuffle).size

def sebastian(arr)
  landscapes, portraits =  arr.sort.slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.to_a
  portraits.each_slice(4).flat_map.with_index { |e, i| e << landscapes[i] }.compact
end

def keith(arr)
  ps, ls = arr.partition { |element| element == 'portrait' }
  result = []    
  loop do
    portrait_count = [4, ps.size].min
    portrait_count.times { result << ps.shift }
    landscape_count = [1, ls.size].min
    landscape_count.times { result << ls.shift }
    break if ps.empty? && ls.empty?
  end
  result
end

compare(
  Sebastian: -> { sebastian arr },
  Keith:     -> { keith arr },
  Cary:      -> { rearrange arr }
)

Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
Cary is faster than Keith by 5x ± 1.0
Keith is similar to Sebastian
```